# Google Extension to work on Google Webstore or Extension Gallery?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I noticed that no extension is able to trigger on the https site:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore

Is this intentional? Is there anyway to get around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is intentional for security reasons. There is no way to get around this :) The Webstore is the new Extension Gallery. The same security that was applied in the Gallery goes for Webstore.